# Examples of uses for the order topology

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

I'm looking for possible interesting uses for order topologies, i.e., topologies generated by rays defined from a total/linear order.

I know for example that continuous maps from compact spaces to one sided order topologies can be used to show the existence of a minimzer or a maximizer.

However, this is the only simple use that springs to mind. Can anyone perhaps give another intersting example of a use for this concept?

Comment: It is useful to build the one point compactification of the natural numbers as topological space $\mathbb{N}\cup \{\omega\} $ with the order topology ($\omega$ being the  first infinite ordinal).

Comment: What is a maximizer?   Are the generating rays open, closed or either?

Comment: @WilliamElliot A maximizer is an element on which the maximum is attained, or at least that's what I meant. The generating rays are open, like in the case of the standard order topology of the real numbers.